# Old science-fiction movie about killer bipedal robots in a desert

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, robots

There is one movie I remember I watched as a kid but can't remember the name. I don't think it was block-buster, but you could rent it on VHS during the 90s.

It involves killer bipedal robots in some desert. It involves time travel, and to travel through time and space, the protagonist had to speed up on some rail and would then be teleported. The rail was placed indoors.

That's what I can remember. I'm sure I'd recognize it from few pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is [*A.P.E.X.*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109144/)

[image]

According to [this site](http://www.badmovies.org/movies/apex/):

> In the year 2072, mankind began to explore time. **Sinclair and Eglin
>   are in charge of the research facility where A.P.E.X. robots are sent
>   through a portal to visit the past.** The acronym A.P.E.X. comes from
>   "Advanced Prototype EXploration units." I suppose that A.P.E.U. is not
>   as impressive an acronym, while ApexU sounds like a university in
>   California. Oh well, moving on. An unfortunate problem with exploring
>   time is that the units become infected with a virus caused by the
>   temporal displacement. As a result, probes are only sent through time
>   to places where they will not come into contact with people. If
>   someone could explain the benefits of going back in time via a metal
>   robot that must avoid human contact because it will cause a plague, I
>   would appreciate the help.

From the same site:

> Yes, they actually send a probe **into the Mojave Desert circa 1973.**